# Error when accessing public relations in models

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, persistence, playframework-1.x

In my project I have trouble with some models. In a controller I call an object inside a model(a ManyToOne relationship) like this:

```
Logger.debug("my model %s", myModel.relObject);
```

This works printing the toString of that relObject. My relObject is defined like this:

```
public class RelObject GenericModel{   
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO) 
@Column(name="My_ID")

public Long myId;    

@Column(name="MY_NAME",  length=24, nullable=false,  unique=false)
@Required
@MaxSize(value=24)
public String myName;   

public toString(){
    return myName;
}    
}
```

However if I code below that logger this:

```
Logger.debug("my model's id %s", myModel.relObject.myId);
```

It sends a null. This is happening in many of my project's models. Any ideas of why and how I can solve this?

Comment: Have you succeed to save any data/record with it? I have tried something similar to your code but I'm not getting `null` value for `myModel.relObject.myId` expression

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. Play lets you do this because you are still in the same Transaction, so you can have access to any field like that without getting nulls. The problem had nothing to do with how I was calling it, or anything like that. It's some kind of bug Play has when you call await() function anywhere in your project. It compiles wierd I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that what was wrong had no sense at all. It appears that there is a bug in play Framework's Controller class. Specifically in the await method that receives only one parameter(A Future object). This method is used when trying to use Future objects such as Promise in order to creat another Thread so that it does not end up blocking the entire application.

If I use this method  anywhere in my project, it does not compile correctly until the second time it is compiled without cleaning the project and causes the models to have an odd behavior.

I will post another topic in stack overflow and googlecode play forum, and I will paste the links to those discuccions in here.